# How to update particular element of local storage in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I am currently storing accessToken and user's info in local storage which is 'userInfo'

Where token will be stored in userInfo.token and userIno will be stored in userInfo.info

I want to update the token inside the userInfo and also want to keep userInfo.info unchanged, Is there any way to do this?

currently I am using this code:

```
localstorage.setItem('userInfo', data.token)
```

but it's deleting userInfo.info

userInfo structure:

```
{"token": eykjdbvksbkvsbks89all, "userinfo": {"email": veera@gmai.com} }
```

Comment: 1. `localStorage` cannot store objects, only strings, and I don't see any serialization code. 2. You cannot modify a nested object in `localStorage` (in part because you can't store objects, see #1) using its API. If you want to store complex data you will need to store it as a string, e.g. using JSON parse/stringify. Did you [read the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)?

Comment: You can `JSON.stringify()` object and store in localstorage  whan you what to update on of its properties get the string object and parse to JSON and modify and set new value

Comment: @RezaGhorbani Yup. Minor nitpick: I think you mean "parse *from* JSON". You might also add that the OP then needs to use `JSON.stringify` again on the result before putting it back in `localStorage`. That would be a great answer!

Comment: Could you please provide code, Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to update the entire `user` object in localStorage.

Example:

```
const user = {"token": "adkadjhk2h3hkhkhkh", "userinfo": {"email": ":veera@gmai.com" } };

localStorage.setItem('userInfo', JSON.stringify(user))

const userInfo = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('userInfo'));

const newUpdatedUserInfo = {
  ...userInfo,
  "token": "new-token-adkadjhk2h3hkhkhkh"
};

localStorage.setItem('userInfo', JSON.stringify(newUpdatedUserInfo))
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this Code example:

```
 localStorage.setItem('userInfo',JSON.stringify({name:'reza',age:20}));
    const data = window.localStorage.getItem('userInfo')
    const newData = JSON.parse(data)
    localStorage.setItem('userInfo',JSON.stringify({...newData,age:44}))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const userInfo = window.localStorage.getItem('userInfo')
const parsedUserInfo = JSON.parse(userInfo)
localStorage.setItem('userInfo', JSON.stringify({...parsedUserInfo,token: data.token }))
```

You can try this snippet.